# Laravel - why do I have errors on one PC and on another none in the same project?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm just starting out with my Laravel project for a subject I have on uni and so far I've been transferring my whole project between those two PCs without any issues, but last time I tried out migrations something interesting happened.

On my laptop at home everything went through fine, it migrated to phpMyAdmin and I saw the columns having the right values for modifiers. When I transferred the next day my project to uni I saw that when I tried to migrate it suddenly gave me a few (easily fixable) errors. Things like string length being too long or description type column not being able to have a default value like I defined.

So my question is: What could be the issue for my project at home not showing those errors, when the exact same project at uni doesn't let me migrate before I fix it all? I work in the same IDE on both PCs (PhpStorm - same version, same account) and both Laravel versions are 6.6.0.

I just want to be sure that I'm not doing mistakes and I can fix my errors at home, not in front of my teacher while giving it to grade it.

Thanks for help

Edit:

Those two lines for example are the ones causing problems on my uni pc, yet at home it goes through without any problems. The error I get are just simple things, something like "key value too long" (for the name column) or "no default value allowed for description type columns"

```
$table->string('name',200)->unique();
$table->text('description')->nullable(true)->default('No description.');
```

Comment: You should provide the error so that will help us.

Comment: I've edited the post, sadly I can't show the errors since I'm on Christmas break now for 3 weeks, but the errors were just simple table construction level errors. Thing is my pc does the migration without any problem.

Comment: Then maybe there is an issue with MySQL engine.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have different PHP or Apache/Nginx versions installed with different configurations, maybe even showing notices for development state. You should try to set up the same server side configuration or consider to use [Docker](https://www.docker.com/) that works across devices as a container system.

Comment: I'm sure that my composer, Laravel, PHP and Apache versions are the same (newest) on both PCs. I might try Docker in the future if I figure out how to properly use it I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Edit file `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php` inside the `boot` method change it to:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}
```

For more information, go to this thread https://laravel-news.com/laravel-5-4-key-too-long-error

Comment: I did that straight away when I started working on my project. At uni it throws an error if I enter a value above 191, yes, but at home I can enter even 2500 and it will go through which is absolutely weird.

Comment: Only MySQL version older than 5.7.7 is affected by this. You might be using newer version.

Comment: That might be the thing, since I don't know what version is on the uni pc. I'll check it after the break, thank you for the help!